# Is there an external spell checker for winedt?

Tags: winedt

Is there an external spell Checker for Winedt such that there is the LanguageTool for TeXstudio?

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Brazilian Portuguese

Comment: You have two (one from the 1990 spelling reform) on this page at [WinEdt.org](http://www.winedt.org/dict.html). On the macros page, you'll find an `InstallDict` macro for an easier installation

Comment: I found the hints interesting. It was very helpful. But other questions occurred to me: is there a way to integrate WinEdt with external tools, such as LanguageTool? Is it possible to use a package, such as spelling (executable only in LuaTeX), which also runs in pdfLaTeX and generates explicit markings for spelling corrections directly in the PDF document? These would be interesting solutions, I believe.

Comment: I have no idea, but you should ask the question on WinEdt mailing list. See [WinEdt support page](http://www.winedt.com/support.html)